# How to get the total COUNT for the results in For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query for one of my search function. A while loop is applied to this query. I have used many sets of if functions inside this while loop to further filter the results as per the user search requirement. And the {email id} (one of the variable in the step1 result) of the final filter result in the if statement set is used to query another table where in a foreach loop is used & obtain other specific details in that table.

```
// WHILE SEARCH PROFILES
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_finda)) {
    $emails=$result['email'];
    $age=$result['age'];
    $name=$result['name'];
    $height=$result['height'];
    $groups=$result['groups'];
    $country=$result['country'];

    if (($age_from <= $age)&& ($age <= $age_to)) {
        $a_emails =$emails;
        $a_age=$age;
        $a_firstname=$name;
        $a_height=$height;
        $a_groups=$groups;
        $a_country=$country;
    }

    if (($height_from <= $a_height)&& ($a_height <= $height_to)) {
        $h_emails =$a_emails;
        $h_age=$a_age;
        $h_firstname=$a_firstname;
        $h_groups=$a_groups;
        $h_country=$a_country;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['groups'] as $workgroup) {
        if (strpos($workgroup, $h_groups) !== false) {
            $m_emails =$h_emails;
            $m_age=$h_age;
            $m_name=$h_name;
            $m_groups=$h_groups;
            $m_country=$h_country;
        }
    }

    foreach ($_POST['country'] as $workcountry) {
        if (strpos($workcountry, $m_country) !== false) {
            $c_emails =$m_emails;
            $c_age=$m_age;
            $c_name=$m_name;
            $c_groups=$m_groups;
            $c_country=$m_country;
        }
    }

    $findeducation="SELECT * FROM education WHERE email='$c_emails'";
    $result_findeducation=mysql_query($findeducation);
    $educationstatus = mysql_fetch_array($result_findeducation);
    $profile_ed=$educationstatus['education'];

    foreach ($_POST['education'] as $educationstatus) {
        if (strpos($educationstatus, $profile_ed) !== false) {
            $e_emails =$_c_emails;
            $e_age=$c_age;
            $e_name=$c_name;
            $e_groups=$c_groups;
            $e_country=$c_country;
            $e_education=$profile_ed;
        }
    }

    if ($e_name) {
        $count++;
    }

    echo $e_name;echo '&nbsp'; 
    echo $e_emails;echo '&nbsp';
    echo $e_age;echo '</br>';
    echo $e_groups;echo '</br>';
    echo $e_country;echo '</br>';
}
```

---

I'm getting the desired result and The results are filtered and shown as per the code above.

My problem is that I'm not getting the total COUNT of the results displayed. Kindly advise for a solution.

Lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE ...` or `mysql_num_rows( $result_finda );` after your original query. Also, mysql_ is deprecated and now removed. Consider using mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Comment: Where in your code you're trying to get the count or print it?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. @fusion3k when I use the query it only give count 1 even if I have 2 result

Comment: Maybe my comment is not clear. I'll write an answer (or you can see at the docs...)

Comment: "DISTINCT *" ?? That ain't gonna work.

Comment: Sorry, @keyem, but your last edit is a very bad practice on SO. Keep in mind that SO is a public site, intended to provide useful info also for future visitors. You can edit yr question by adding details, but you don't have to change the question topic. Otherwise, provided ansers make not sense. You have to mark this question as answered choosing useful answer (if any), then you can ask for a new one. Please note that a well formed new question is also the best method to obtain more attention and reputation. In minutes, I'll roll back your last edit. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Thank you @fusion3k. Sorry for that. I'm new to this and asking questions. Because I'm desperate in resolving the issue, I have done this. Pardon me if its not the wright way. also help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

SQL :

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result_finda);
```

PHP :

```
$count = count(mysql_fetch_array($result_finda));
```

**EDIT**

Use the following :

```
$count = 0; // Initialize $count

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_finda))
{
    // Filter your results
    $count++; // Increment $count for each result that matches with your filters
} 

print $count; // number of results after filtering
```

In your code :

```
$finda="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE gender='$gender'";
$result_finda=mysql_query($finda);
$count = 0;

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_finda)) {
    $emails=$result['email'];
    $age=$result['age'];
    $name=$result['name'];
    $height=$result['height'];
    $groups=$result['groups'];
    $country=$result['country'];

    if (($age_from <= $age)&& ($age <= $age_to)) {
        $a_emails =$emails;
        $a_age=$age;
        $a_firstname=$name;
        $a_height=$height;
        $a_groups=$groups;
        $a_country=$country;
    }

    if (($height_from <= $a_height)&& ($a_height <= $height_to)) {
        $h_emails =$a_emails;
        $h_age=$a_age;
        $h_firstname=$a_firstname;
        $h_groups=$a_groups;
        $h_country=$a_country;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['groups'] as $workgroup) {
        if (strpos($workgroup, $h_groups) !== false) {
            $m_emails =$h_emails;
            $m_age=$h_age;
            $m_name=$h_name;
            $m_groups=$h_groups;
            $m_country=$h_country;
        }
    }

    foreach ($_POST['country'] as $workcountry) {
        if (strpos($workcountry, $m_country) !== false) {
            $c_emails =$m_emails;
            $c_age=$m_age;
            $c_name=$m_name;
            $c_groups=$m_groups;
            $c_country=$m_country;
        }
    }

    $findeducation="SELECT * FROM education WHERE email='$c_emails'";
    $result_findeducation=mysql_query($findeducation);
    $educationstatus = mysql_fetch_array($result_findeducation);
    $profile_ed=$educationstatus['education'];

    foreach ($_POST['education'] as $educationstatus) {
        if (strpos($educationstatus, $profile_ed) !== false) {
            $e_emails =$_c_emails;
            $e_age=$c_age;
            $e_name=$c_name;
            $e_groups=$c_groups;
            $e_country=$c_country;
            $e_education=$profile_ed;
        }
    }

    if ($e_name) {
        $count++;
    }

    echo $e_name;echo '&nbsp'; 
    echo $e_emails;echo '&nbsp';
    echo $e_age;echo '</br>';
    echo $e_groups;echo '</br>';
    echo $e_country;echo '</br>';
}

print "$count RESULTS"; // [number] RESULTS
```

Comment: hi chalasr. but the result in my query for $result_finda is filtered through criteria in if statement, so the $count = count(mysql_fetch_array($result_finda));donot match with the final result count

Comment: I get 0 results even though I have 2 result

Comment: You are surely doing something wrong ... Be sure that `$count = 0` is before the `while`, and `$count++` in the last condition : `if (strpos($educationstatus, $profile_ed) !== false) { $count++; // ... }`